# Basic Iptables question (Open connection both ways)

Tags: firewall, iptables, port

I am trying to open a connection on a machine both ways. That is I am trying to open say the port 8001 and I did this.

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8001 -j ACCEPT

Now how to configure so the server lets the outgoing packets generated by the program listening on 8001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8001 -j ACCEPT`

You can also use the connection tracking take care of it, with something like `iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` -- some people have preferences one way or the other, use whichever one suits you better.

Comment: I need to specify a protocol after -p right. Because it gives me an error. But I went ahed and put tcp like this. 

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8001 -j ACCEPT

After configuring with the above command and the previous one I mentioned, I did nmap localhost - but I do not see 8001 listed in there. How to check if things worked (before actually waiting for other programs to start using 8001)

Comment: Yeah, need a protocol for `-p`.  Answer updated.  I normally test TCP ports with netcat and tcpdump.